# Matrix, Ranks and Rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $f:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. Given bases $\{v_i\}_{1\leq i \leq n}$ and $\{w_j\}_{1\leq j \leq m}$ of V and W, respectively, $f$ has an associated $m \times n$ matrix $A$.

I am having trouble showing the the dimension of the row space equals the rank of $f$. I can't use the fact that the rank of the transpose of a matrix equals the rank of the matrix.

I know that the rank of a matrix is the rank of the column space of $A$ and I know how to show that if I have two bases $B$ and $C$, and a linear transformation $f$ and $A=\mathrm{Mat}_{B,C}(f)$, we have $\mathrm{rank}(f)=\mathrm{rank}(A)$. But I am having trouble establishing the connection with the row space.

I am having trouble showing as well that the row space and the nullspace span $V$. I think I need to show the the sum of the row space and the nullspace equal $V$ but I am not sure how to show that. Does the intersection between the row space and the nullspace correspond to $\{0\}$ ?

Thank you

The issue with the previous answer was that it used the relation that the rank of the transpose of a matrix equals the rank of the matrix, which I am not allowed to use.

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)

Comment: By definition, we know that the rank of a matrix equals the rank of the column space. I can then show that rank of the linear transformation equals rank of the representative matrix of T in the bases of V and W. And then, I can show that rank of the column space equals rank of the row space. Is there perhaps a shorter way?

Comment: Yes, the rank of $f$ is equal to the (column) rank of $A$ for every matrix $A$ of $f$. Then it mounts to showing that the rank of $A$ is equal to the rank of its transpose. You have three different proofs on the wiki page I linked. Not sure there is a shorter way.

Comment: Can you help me with the second question please?

Comment: I have to run now, but I'll be back pretty soon.

Comment: Yes. Basically if we call R the row space and N(T) the nullspace, I need to show that R+N(T)=V

Comment: The rowspace is a space of rows, the nullspace is a space of columns. You need to make this a little bit more rigorous. I think you want to prove that $R(A^T) + N(A) = V$.

Comment: Can you detail things a little more please

Comment: The range space of the transpose of $A$ plus the nullspace of $A$ span $V$.

Comment: But how do I show it ?

Comment: So, that's what you are trying to show? Also, is your field the real numbers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7668/discussion-between-user43758-and-manos)

Comment: Can someone help me with the second question ?

Comment: It would probably be easier to just prove that the nullspace is the orthogonal complement of the rowspace. In either case, the same idea will easily show that the two spaces have null intersection.

Comment: @EuYu: This works when our field is the reals or the complex numbers.

Comment: @julien The OP is still waiting for you. Come and save the day!

Comment: Can anybody help ?

Comment: @GitGud Ah! Ah! I think there are about one million people here who can answer this.

Comment: @julien Can you help me please?

Comment: You can start a thread on meta.math.stackexchange asking for this question to be reopened and giving your justification. Alternatively, you can edit your earlier question to indicate why you are dissatisfied with the answer.

Comment: But I told you that I can't use the fact that rank (t_A)=rank(A)

Comment: @user43758 But I am afraid this is circular. Your first question is: prove that the rank of $f$ is the dimension of the row space. The latter explicitly refers to a matrix $A$ of $f$ with respect, for instance, to the bases you mentioned. And then trivially the rank of $f$ is the dimension of the column space of the same $A$. So your question is essentially: prove that the rank of $A$ is equal to the rank of $A^t$. And you say you don't want to use it. Sure, since that's what you have to prove.

Comment: Could you say what you define the rank to be?  There are several equivalent definitions and it would help to know which one you are working from.

Comment: If you have an issue  with the previous answer, you should raise it with the author of the previous answer, pointing out that a certain fact should not be used in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be $m \times n$ over an arbitrary field $F$. Then $\dim(R(A))=\dim(R(A^T))={\rm rank}(A)$ and $\dim(R(A^T))+\dim N(A)=n$.

This is not enough to show that $R(A^T)+N(A) = F^n$.
Counterexample: Let $F=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $A=[1 \, \, \, 1]$. Then $N(A) = <[1 \, \, \, 1]^T>=R(A^T)$ and $R(A^T)+N(A)=N(A) \neq \mathbb{Z}_2 ^ 2$.

If $F=\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) we proceed as follows: Take $x \in R(A^T) \cap N(A)$. Then $x = A^T y$ and so $0=Ax=A A^T y \Rightarrow 0=y^T A A^T y = ||A^Ty||_2^2 \Rightarrow ||A^T y||_2=0 \Rightarrow 0=A^Ty=x$ and so $R(A^T) \cap N(A)=0$. Hence $$\dim[ R(A^T) + N(A)]= \dim(R(A^T))+\dim N(A)= n \Rightarrow F^n = R(A^T) + N(A)$$.

Comment: I take it that $R(A)$ and $N(A)$ stand for the row and null spaces of $A$, respectively. No, wait, $R(A)$ must be the range of $A$, or of the associated linear transformation $f$, so it's actually the column space of $A$, and $R(A^t)$ is the row space of $A$. But surely this can be done without introducing the $2$-norm.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the notation. I am interested in seeing a proof without using the 2-norm.